# How to clear buffer after reading an input in c?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void generarDimension(int, void **, int);
void reallocarDimensiones(int, void **, int);
void preguntarValor(int *);
char *generarCadena(char *);

typedef struct listaAlu{//this is a list of students
    char cedula[7];//this means id
    char *nombreApellido;//this means name and lastname
    short curso;//this means the year of the student in college/school
    unsigned short anho;//and this means year-E.g: 2017
};

int main(void){
    struct listaAlu *alu = NULL;
    int salir=1;
    char c;
    unsigned int cont = 0;
    unsigned int i;
    size_t size = 0;
    struct listaAlu *temp = NULL;
    while(salir!=0){//Condition until user press exit option
        printf("Agregar Alumno?Ingrese 1 para Agregar, y 0 para salir\n");//This means "Add student?Press 1 to add, and 0 to exit
        preguntarValor(&salir);//this verifies user input
        if(salir==1){//if user adds then it asks info of the student
            cont++;
            if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( alu, size + 2))) {//realloc for each character input and '\0'
                fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
            }//this is for increasing the number of students
            alu = temp;
            printf("Ingrese Cedula:\n");//This means "Enter id"
            scanf("%s", &(alu+(size))->cedula);
            printf("Ingrese Nombre y Apellido:\n");//This means "Enter name and lastname"
            (alu+(size))->nombreApellido = generarCadena((alu+(size))->nombreApellido);
            printf("Ingrese Curso:\n");//This means enter college/school year
            scanf("%hd", &(alu+(size))->curso);
            printf("Ingrese Anho:\n");//and this means "Enter year"
            scanf("%hd", &(alu+(size))->anho);
            size++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<cont;i++){
        printf("\tAlumno %d\n", i+1);
        printf("Nombre:\t%s\n", (alu+i)->nombreApellido);
        printf("Cedula:\t%s\n", (alu+i)->cedula);
        printf("Curso:\t%d\n", (alu+i)->curso);
        printf("Anho:\t%d\n", (alu+i)->anho);
    }//This prints Everything the user entered
    free(alu);
    return 0;
}//Sorry for writing my program entirely on the main >.<

void generarDimension(int bloques, void **ptr, int tamanho){
    void **ptrAux;
    *ptrAux = malloc(bloques * tamanho);
    if(*ptrAux==NULL){
        printf("No se pudo almacenar memoria\n");
    }else{
            *ptr = *ptrAux;
            free(ptrAux);
        }
}//this I didn't use, but it is for generating an array through a pointer
void reallocarDimensiones(int bloques, void **ptr, int tamanho){
    void **ptrAux;
    *ptrAux = realloc(*ptr,bloques * tamanho);
    if(*ptrAux==NULL){
        printf("No se pudo almacenar memoria\n");
    }else{
            *ptr = *ptrAux;
            free(ptrAux);
        }
}//This I didn't either, but it is for reallocating any given pointer

void preguntarValor(int *n){
    long entero, lector;
    *n=-2;
    do{
        printf("\nSi ingresa otro numero o caracter, vuelva a ingresar opcion\n");
        while(!scanf("%d", &entero)){
            while((lector=getchar()) !='\n' && lector !=EOF );
        }
        *n=entero;
    }while(*n>1 || *n<0);//You can change this parameters according to the numbers you want
}//This subrutine scans only integers between 1 and 0

char *generarCadena(char *scaneado){
    char *temp = NULL;
    int in = 0;
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( '\n' != ( in = getchar ( ))) {//loop until newline
        if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( scaneado, size + 2))) {//realloc for each character input and '\0'
            fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
            return scaneado;
        }
        scaneado = temp;
        scaneado[size] = in;//set input
        scaneado[size + 1] = '\0';//terminate
        size++;
    }
    return scaneado;
}//This subrutine is for geting an input of chars of any given length
```

This is a program to store a college/school student list, I want to know how to improve this code, however in the part where I ask the user to enter strings, on the second one I can't enter anything. And if I try to enter more than 2 students, my code doesn't print all the info of the students I entered

Comment: Trim code to the problem you want to solve. It is hard to read whole of your program just to solve buffer cleanup scenario.

Comment: `while (!scanf("%d", &entero))` should use `"%ld"`.  Enable all warnings to see this and other short comings.

Comment: `void **ptrAux;
  *ptrAux = realloc(*ptr, bloques * tamanho);` does not make sense.  `ptrAux` is de-referenced, yet `ptrAux` was never assigned a value.  `*ptrAux` is UB.  At least 2 places in code.

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski actually it has more buggs >.<, which are explained after the code...It's just that the one in the tittle is more notorious xD

Comment: Tip: when posting such problems, include input used, output seen, output expected.

Comment: @chux I'm a newbie, but i experimented whit that code, and I can send you the proto for you to see how it works

Comment: Best to include in your post the  input,output, expectations as _text_, not photo.

Comment: @chux https://pastebin.com/XJF11QhU I posted my proto code here, so you can see. It runs and works, or at least it seems to work. Just enter some numbers and you will see what it does

Comment: Enable warnings, and fix them before posting.  You're taking the address of a `char` array, resulting in an array pointer, and passing it to `scanf` when reading a string.  You need to pass a `char *`, which you can achieve by removing the address-of operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct listaAlu *temp = NULL;
temp = realloc ( alu, size + 2);//<- wrong size
```

`realloc(alu, size + 2)` will allocate only 2 bytes in the first run. But you need much more than that. The total size needed is number of elements in the array multiply by the size of the structure. That is `sizeof(struct listaAlu)` which is about 15 bytes.

```
realloc( alu, sizeof(struct listaAlu) * (size + 1) );
```

You don't need to increment the size by `2`.

Make sure to check the input at the right places. Clear the input when `scanf` fails.

To get first name and last name, you can use `fgets` and `strdup`

There are major problems with `generarDimension` and `reallocarDimensiones`. You may want to leave those out.

```
struct listaAlu{
    char cedula[7];//this means id
    char *nombreApellido;//this means name and lastname
    short curso;//this means the year of the student in college/school
    unsigned short anho;//and this means year-E.g: 2017
};

void clear()
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct listaAlu *alu = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        alu = realloc( alu, sizeof(struct listaAlu) * (size + 1) );
        if (!alu)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc problem\n");
            break;
        }

        char buf[256] = { 0 };

        printf("Enter id:\n");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\r\n")] = 0;
        buf[sizeof(alu[size].cedula) - 1] = 0;
        strcpy(alu[size].cedula, buf);

        printf("Enter name and lastname:\n");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\r\n")] = 0;
        alu[size].nombreApellido = _strdup(buf);

        for(;;)
        {
            printf("Enter college/school year:\n");
            if (scanf("%hd", &alu[size].curso) == 1)
                break;

            printf("input error\n");
            clear();
        }

        for(;;)
        {
            printf("Enter year:\n");
            if (scanf("%hd", &alu[size].anho) == 1)
                break;

            printf("input error\n");
            clear();
        }

        size++;

        printf("Press 1 to continue\n");
        char input;
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        if(input != '1')
            break;
        clear();
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Alumno %d\n", i);
        printf("Nombre:\t%s\n", alu[i].nombreApellido);
        printf("Cedula:\t%s\n", alu[i].cedula);
        printf("Curso:\t%hd\n", alu[i].curso);
        printf("Anho:\t%hd\n", alu[i].anho);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free(alu[i].nombreApellido);
    free(alu);
    return 0;
}
```

---

***Edit***

`realloc` does not need to be wrapped in a different function. But for fun purposes, you can do the following:

```
void* my_realloc1(void *ptr, int size)
{
    ptr = realloc(ptr, size);
    if (!ptr) printf("error\n");  
    return ptr;
}

//usage:
alu = my_realloc1(alu, sizeof(struct listaAlu) * (size + 1));
if (!alu) printf("error\n");
```

`my_realloc1` will work here, however nothing is gained. This is just extra lines of code. It's easier and more clear to use `realloc` directly and do the necessary error handling.

Another method is to pass a reference:

```
void my_realloc2(void **ptr, int size)
{
    *ptr = realloc(*ptr, size);
}

//usage: (*** Note the address `&` operator ***)
my_realloc2(&alu, sizeof(struct listaAlu) * (size + 1));
if (!alu) printf("error\n");
```

Again this will work, but it just adds more code.

The function `generarCadena` seems okay. You could simplify as follows:

```
char *my_getline()
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    int in = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    while('\n' != (in = getchar()))
    {
        size++;
        buf = realloc(buf, size);
        buf[size - 1] = (char)in;
    }

    size++;
    buf = realloc(buf, size);
    buf[size - 1] = 0;

    return buf;
}

//usage:
printf("Enter name and lastname:\n");
alu[size].nombreApellido = my_getline();
```

And use `scanf` for to read 6 characters (because size of `cedula` is 7)

```
printf("Enter 6 characters:\n");
scanf("%6s", alu[size].cedula);
alu[size].cedula[6] = '\0';
clear();
```

To be safe, make sure the input is null terminated, and clear the buffer.

Or you can use `fgets` as I used in the example. This will read up to 256 characters:

```
char buf[256];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

`fgets` is sometimes easier because you don't need to clear the buffer. But `buf` includes end of line character `\n`, you have to remove `\n` in this case.

Comment: char buf[256] = { 0 }; ->In this part I have a question...Why did you use 256? Is it a constant? does that means the maximum of characters a user can input?And is there a way of fixing reallocarDimensiones and generarDimension, or should I write those again?

Comment: Yes, 256 is arbitrary number. It assumes the user will not enter more than 256 characters. If input is longer it will be chopped. Maybe my example of `fgets` was convoluted. See edited answer.

Comment: But in the "my_realloc2" wouldn't it be necessary to use an auxiliar pointer and then asign the adrress of it to the one you send on the parameter? Someone told me yesterday to do that to prevent memory leaks, so I tried to follow the advice and used an auxiliar void pointer.Thanks for your patience by the way xd

Comment: No, `my_realloc2` is correct the way it is (and it is also unnecessary). Use `realloc` directly in the code. Use `free` when you are done with the memory. You can ask or research `realloc`. Your question is more about "passing pointers in C" or "modify pointers in C". You could rewrite `my_realloc2` as `{void *ptrAux = *ptr; ptrAux = realloc(ptrAux, size); *ptr = ptrAux;}` In practice avoid introducing new pointers unless you really need them.